# How to call rest api and do not wait any response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous

I have this code

```
private Boolean doSomething() {
    // SOME CODE
    this.sync();
    return true;
}

public void sync() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();
    restTemplate.exchange(batchHost, HttpMethod.GET, header(), String.class);
}
```

I don't need data from the rest call. it's batch execution service he take times. but for my `doSomething` function i don't need a response from `sync` to continue.

Today, when the rest call not working, not available... my function doSomething .... do nothing...

How to call rest service but continue without error `doSomething()` without errors ??

Thanks

I use java 11

Comment: don't call the service at all or call it using a thread

Comment: Use an async call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the `sync` method call asynchronous. Spring provides easy way to do that. Add `@EnableAsync` in any of you Configuration class (i.e. Classes annotated with `@Configuration`). If you don't find any configuration class then add `@EnableAsync` in the class with `@SpringBootApplication`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SpringbootApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then add `@Async` to your `sync` method. Your code will look like this.

```
@Async
public void sync() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();
    restTemplate.exchange(batchHost, HttpMethod.GET, header(), String.class);
}
```

To make `@Async` work, this `sync` method need to be called from another class file. If you call `sync` from same class then sync method will not be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use RestTemplate to call REST API.

"Please, consider using the org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient which has a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios."

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner, if i understand i must use WebClient with an async call ?
how to make an async call without response needed ?
thanks

Comment: @Florian You do not have to - RestTemplate is just deprecated and you should learn to use the WebClient instead. There are plenty of tutorials these days and the new approach is much better and more capable, but to be honest the API is not so intuitive to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a response from the methods you run async, then You can simply do the async portion inside `completableFuture` lambda method as follows, directly in your triggering endpoint and return 200 ok immediately.  Note, if internal method may throw exceptions, you need to swallow that too in a try/catch to ensure it happens asynch. as well.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/trigger")
    public ResponseEntity<String> triggerMethod() throws Exception {
        

          CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
              try {
                
                this.dosomething();

              } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

          });
          
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        
        
    }
```

However, if you require a response through other methods run asynchronously, then you will need to implement something like [this example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/enableasync-async-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Spring WebFlux*** to build or consume API's in reactive and non-blocking manners.
Here is the official documentation which explains this in detail:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html